# CUDA Warp Execution Efficiency

Tags: performance, cuda, gpgpu, gpu

I can obtain warp_execution_efficiency for each kernel, but how can I obtain total warp_execution_efficiency of my program?

Answer (score 3):

Note: Calculating a single number across all kernels is unlikely to be useful for optimization purposes.

NVIDIA's profiler is kernel-centric, so directly querying that information is impossible. You can, however, run `nvprof --csv --metrics warp_execution_efficiency`, then put the output into Excel, R, or your favorite statistical software and mess with it there.

One problem with this is that warp_execution_efficiency involves an average, so you can't just take the average. You might be able to get some handy visualizations that the Visual Profiler doesn't offer.